# Is there methods to detect Windows-11 vs Windows-10 in Firefox browser?

Tags: javascript, firefox, user-agent, windows-11, os-detection

Currently,
    On **Windows-11** devices I'm getting  `navigator.userAgent` value as `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.5060.134 Safari/537.36 Edg/103.0.1264.77` which is same as **Windows-10**.

To distinguish between Windows-10 vs Windows-11, I have used [User-Agent Client Hints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/web-platform/how-to-detect-win11)

```
navigator.userAgentData.getHighEntropyValues(['platformVersion']).then(function(uapv){
    console.log(uapv.platformVersion); 
    var winVer = Number(uapv.platformVersion.split('.')[0]);
    if(winVer>10){
        console.log("It's Win11")
    }else{
        console.log("It's Not Win11");
    }
});
```

But,
    **User-Agent Client Hints** are only supported in *Chrome/Edge/Opera* but not in *Firefox*.

**So, is there a technique/library available to detect Windows-11 in *Firefox* ?**

Comment: Why do you "need" that information?

Comment: I want to detect the user machine's OS to give them targeted offers. But the windows-11 machine is being detected as windows-10 in firefox.

Answer (score -3):

Try this library:

https://github.com/bestiejs/platform.js

Then, do `platform.os`
and it should give you something like: `Windows Server 2008 R2 / 7 x64`
the `7` is the version here.

Comment: [This doesn't detect Windows 11](https://github.com/bestiejs/platform.js/issues/199)